# Sharepoint 2013 Usage Reports not fetching data (showing 0 everywhere)

Tags: site-usage

SharePoint 2013 Usage Reports not fetching data (showing 0 everywhere)

The below things are already checked :

- I made sure the Usage and Health Data Collection was configured
- I verified that the WSS_Admin_WPG and WSS_WPG groups both had full
  access to the Log File Location
- I made sure both the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data
  Import and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing
  timer jobs were enabled and able to run successfully.